# TableSorter: hideFilters doesn't work with StickyHeader

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

With jQuery TableSorter script, it seems there is a problem with the StickyHeader when used with hideFilters. Actually, the filter row doesn't open on mouseover when header is frozen on top of the page.

See the problem here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ted22/SrLZu/5/

```
widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
widgetOptions: {
    filter_columnFilters: true,
    filter_hideFilters: true,
    filter_searchDelay: 300
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It worked for me. Using FF 28

Comment: Hey, that looks like a bug... I'll have it fixed in the next update.

Comment: This problem has been fixed in v2.16.3. Thanks for reporting it!